# Printing 2D Grid From List of Triples

Tags: haskell

I want to print list of triples in a line by line manner. The list contains triples that every first element of the triples should be placed in the coordinates given as the second and the third elements of the tirples. The grid starts from (0,0) coordinates.
below is a 2x2 grid example:

```
generateGrid [('a',0,0),('b',0,2),('c',1,1), ('d',2,2)]
-> a - b
   - c -
   - - d
```

I have an approach to generate this function but I couldn't put everything in code.
I tried to find the maximum number in the triples and create the grid by its incremented value. In that way I could start from (0,0) cooradinate. Then, I wanted to go over all the triples and put the first element in the related coordinate.
How can I make this approach?

Below is my code:

```
gridMax ((p1, p2, p3):xs) = max (maximum(secList ((p1, p2, p3):xs))) (maximum(thirdList ((p1, p2, p3):xs)))

secList [] = []
secList ((p1, p2, p3):xs) = [p2] ++ secList xs

thirdList [] = []
thirdList ((p1, p2, p3):xs) = [p3] ++ thirdList xs
```

this way I found the max of the grid which means I should create a (max+1)X(max+1) grid starting from (0,0). I couldn't get the rest of the code.

Comment: How about you show us what you managed to put in code? — As for the algorithm... I'd do this with a sort–group–interleave‐space approch. No need to know the total number of triples.

Comment: I edited my question and shared some of my work.

Comment: I'm not marking as duplicate because your question is at least coherent, but someone asked a similar question the other day that I gave some hints for.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997734/print-function-drawf-from-a-list-of-tuples/22998207

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the laziness of Haskell, we can suppose that we have an infinite grid, so we could just set cells on this grid according the coordinates given in arguments one by one, and record the size of the result grid in this process. When we finished, we could just take the result grid from that infinite grid.

Here is an implementation of this idea:

```
setVal :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
setVal idx val lst = h ++ (val : tail t)
    where (h, t) = splitAt idx lst

setCell :: (Char, Int, Int) -> [[Char]] -> [[Char]]
setCell (c, x, y) grid = setVal x xl grid
    where xl = setVal y c $ grid !! x

generateGrid :: [(Char, Int, Int)] -> [[Char]]
generateGrid cs = take (mx+1) $ map (take (my+1)) grid
    where (mx, my, grid) = foldr step (0, 0, g) cs
          g = repeat $ repeat '-'
          step co@(c, x, y) (mx, my, g) =
            let g' = setCell co g
                mx' = max x mx
                my' = max y my
            in
                (mx', my', g')
```

Could be tested like this:

```
*Main> let cs = [('a',0,0),('b',0,2),('c',1,1), ('d',2,2)] :: [(Char, Int, Int)] 
*Main> putStr $ unlines $ generateGrid cs
a-b
-c-
--d
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me alot to other related steps.

Comment: @nudaStck You could try and see what happens :-)

Comment: :) Ofcourse, I tried it but it gives type error as:  Type           : [(Char,Integer,Integer)] Does not match : [(Char,Int,Int)].

Comment: I was able to solve it :) Thank you again. I will erase that short question.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here is the Haskell One-Liner:

```
generateGrid :: [((Int, Int), Char)] -> String 
generateGrid xs = 
  unlines $ map (map snd) $ groupBy ((==) `on` fst . fst) $ assocs $ accumArray (const id) '-' ((0,0), (maximum $ map (fst . fst) xs, maximum $ map (snd . fst) xs)) xs
```

Lets decode what is going on here:

```
generateGrid :: [((Int, Int), Char)] -> String 
generateGrid xs = 
  unlines .                         
  map (map snd) .
  groupBy ((==) `on` fst . fst) . 
  assocs .
  accumArray (const id) 
             '-' 
             ((0,0), (maximum $ map (fst . fst) xs, maximum $ map (snd . fst) xs))       
  $ xs
```

The first thing we do is create an array using `accumArray :: (e -> a -> e) -> e -> (i, i) -> [(i, a)] -> Array i e`. It takes a 'default' element - here `'-'` for obvious reasons; a combining function, here `const id` - which just returns the second element, which will be the elements drawn from the list; a range, starting at `(0,0)` and ending at the maximum values; and finally, `xs` the input list, which is a list of keys `(Int, Int)` associated with values: `Char`.

The entire point of this is to "fill in" the empty spaces with `((x,y),'-')`. `accumArray` is a very easy way of doing this.

Then we use `assocs` to get a list back out of the array.

The next function will take the list of associations and group them into sublists - each sublist containing one row.

Now we have a list of rows - we aren't interested in the indices any longer, so `map (map snd)` gets rid of them. Finally, `unlines` combines the rows into a single string seperated by newlines.